# How to validate extra field added to the customer information in admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, form-validation

In my custom module i added two extra field to the customer information displayed in `admin->Customers->CustomerInformation->AccountInformation` using install file. Now i want to add the validation to newly added field how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to validate the field added to customer in admin area.

in install file we have to add a field to attribute.

'frontend_class' => 'validation-class'

where validation-class is the valid validation rules provided by magento in js/prototype/validation.js.